# Scraping data from a website with Cheerio and Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, cheerio

considering the website: https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin/

I'm trying to extract the value $23,073.15 (that changes continuosly) of the following span class.

`span class="typography__StyledTypography-owin6q-0 fZpnIj">$23,073.15</span`

I tried the following code with Google script using Cheerio without success:

````
var URL = "https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin/";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
var itemsOfInterest = $('span.typography__StyledTypography-owin6q-0 fZpnIj').text();```


any help about?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the HTML data from your URL using Google Apps Script, unfortunately, it seems that the data is retrieved from an API by Javascript. By this, in this case, your expected value cannot be retrieved from your URL with cheerio. So, in this answer, I would like to propose retrieving your expected value using the API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const url = "https://production.api.coindesk.com/v2/tb/price/ticker?assets=BTC";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const value = obj.data.BTC.ohlc.l;
  console.log(value)
}
```

- I think that when this script is run, you can see your expected value in the log.

Comment: Thanks, how did you get the API URL? "https://production.api.coindesk.com/v2/tb/price/ticker?assets=BTC"

Comment: @pila pila8 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I couldn't understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? About your new question of `did you get the API URL? "production.api.coindesk.com/v2/tb/price/ticker?assets=BTC"`, this can be seen with the developer tools of Chrome, when the URL is accessed.

Comment: @pila pila8 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike, can you please guide from where can we get this url in developers tool: `production.api.coindesk.com/v2/tb/price/ticker?assets=BTC`